# Comment se fait-il que les Français sachent prononcer [ŋ]?

Tags: anglais, histoire, phonétique, linguistique

Le son `[ŋ]` n'existe en français que dans les mots d'origine étrangère, surtout anglaise. Cependant, les Français le prononcent « correctement », c'est-à-dire presque exactement comme les anglophones. On constate par exemple la différence entre le « r » dans « parking », prononcé à la française, et le « ng » à la fin du même mot. Comment, quand, et pourquoi les Français ont appris à prononcer ce son étranger ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

L'explication phonologique habituelle repose sur la neuvième règle de [Трубецкой](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Nikola%C3%AF_Troubetzko%C3%AF)<sup>1</sup> dite *règle d'équilibre structural*.

Le français a une structure [phonématique](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Phon%C3%A8me) à trois séries de trois [occlusives](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Occlusive) (voir tableau ci-dessous) et tend à la conserver. Or la voyelle [`[ɲ]`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Palatal_nasal.ogg) à tendance à disparaître au profit de la série `[nj]` — en gros on prononce de plus en plus le *gn* d'*agneau* comme le *ni* de *panier*.

La disparition de `[ɲ]` déséquilibre la structure en ne laissant que deux occlusives dans la série nasale (`[m]` et `[n]`). La langue rétablit son équilibre en ajoutant la nasale [`[ŋ]`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Velar_nasal.ogg) qui était auparavant prononcée `[nj]` ou `voyelle nasale + [g]` et qui est plus proche phonétiquement de ses homologues dans les séries occlusives non-nasales (`[k]` et `[g]`)<sup>2</sup>.

C'est plus clair en regardant le tableau des occlusives du français.

[image: Tableau des occlusives du français]

C'est un changement assez récent, environ une cinquantaine d'années d'après mes profs, l'exemple donné était de Queneau qui utilisait dans *Zazie dans le métro* des orthographes reflétant la prononciation du type *campigne* ou *parkingue* (à vérifier).

---

<sup>1</sup> Très précisément

> Règle 9 (équilibre structural)
>
> Un groupe phonique répondant aux règles 1 à 3 doit être considéré comme l’une des     réalisations d’un phonème si cela rétablit un parallélisme dans l’inventaire des phonèmes.

<sup>2</sup> Au cas où un linguiste passerait par là : oui, je sais que `/k/` et `/g/` se réalisent `[c]` et `[ɟ]` devant les voyelles antérieures et sont donc plus proches de `[ɲ]` dans ce cas. L'argument de proximité n'est donc pas tout à fait recevable.

Comment: J'ai rien compris, mais ça à l'air intéressant.

Comment: Mieux comme ça?

Comment: Ça change tout ! Allez +1, même si lejpegçafaitmalauxyeux.

Answer (score 10):

Est-ce vraiment un son étranger ?
Il s'entend beaucoup dans le sud de la France il me semble, dans des mots comme "demain" ou "putain".
Il est possible que le son "ng" ait été utilisé dans de nombreux patois et qu'il ait subsisté chez une partie des populations de la France.

Enfin, je serais tenté de conclure à la va-vite en disant que "ng" n'est rien d'autre que la composition de deux sons qu'on trouve déjà en français, et qu'il n'y a rien d'exceptionnel là, si ce n'est que cette combinaison ne se retrouve que dans des mots d'origine étrangère.

Comment: Composition de deux sons ? Lesquels ?

Comment: "n" et "g" :)  Tous les français ne savent pas prononcer correctement [ŋ], mais c'est un sont *très proche* de "n" suivi de "g", et c'est un son qu'ils entendent depuis longtemps via l'Anglais omniprésent, et via certains patois.  Il est donc assez facile je crois à acquérir.

Answer (score 9):

Ce qui est amusant, c'est que tu as choisi *parking* comme exemple, alors qu'il s'agit d'un nom commun spécifique au français, comme *dancing*, forgés à partir d'adverbes anglais (si je ne me trompe pas dans la terminologie, la grammaire n'est pas mon point fort !).
Je viens juste de vérifier (ce que j'ai appris il y a longtemps), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parking) ne connait ce mot que pour *parking brake* et *parking light*.
Bon, évidemment, la nature grammatical du mot ne doit pas trop changer la prononciation, ce qui compte est l'exemple phonétique, je suppose.

Pour revenir à la question, je pense qu'il y a deux facteurs :

- Tout d'abord, c'est par mimétisme : on prononce comme on a entendu prononcé. Ceux qui ont importé les termes devaient connaître un tant soit peu l'anglais, et l'ont prononcé comme ils l'ont entendu.
- Ensuite, comme dit Axiolase, ce n'est pas un son difficile à reproduire pour un français, contrairement à, disons, th. La combinaison phonétique, même si elle est reproduite approximativement, n'est pas acrobatique.

Comment: Le terme américain pour «parking» est «parking lot».  (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parking%20lot) Shampooing, par contre...

Comment: It's perfectly possible for an American to be shampooing their hair (when the phone rings or whatever).  Radically different from the French noun, agreed

Answer (score 6):

Si je ne me trompe pas `[ŋ]` est un `[n]` prononcé avec l'extrémité de la langue à plat contre le palais (plutôt que la pointe de la langue pour le `[n]`), ce qui est la position de départ du `[g]`. Si un francophone prononce `[ng]`, il va avoir tendance à prononcer en fait `[nŋg]`, roulant la langue, il « suffit » de ne garder que la consonne du milieu. Ce qui n'est pas facile. J'ai l'impression —  mais je en suis pas linguiste et je n'ai donc pas l'oreille particulièrement bien éduquée —  que face à `ng` les francophones prononcent `[ŋg]` voire `[nŋg]` mais relativement rarement le `[ŋ]` désiré.

Answer (score 1):

Je me demande si dans un français parlé de manière rapide et relâché, le son /n/ ne s'assimile pas, pour ce qui est du lieu d'articulation, au son consonantique suivant.

*une catastrophe* ne serait pas prononcé /ynkatastrɔf/ mais /yŋkatastrɔf/

C'est certainement le cas en italien :

un caffè /uŋ ka'f:ɛ/

Instinctivement, je pense que c'est possible, auquel cas, vu la fréquence de la séquence une + mot commençant par /k/ ou /g/, il serait naturel que la nasale vélaire ne pose pas de problème aux locuteurs du français.